# GSON fromJson stackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, gson, stack-overflow

I'm trying to parse the following json

```
{
  "Id": "233ffba3-9796-4fff-32e3-535116e1297c",
  "Content": "lorem ipsum",
  "DateCreated": "2014-12-06T16:02:25Z",
  "ChatId": "33485bff-a95f-4a19-982d-532364db384d",
  "AccountId": "2da98191-c3de-49f0-a424-89ba7a0f448e",
  "Internal": false,
  "Quotation": false
}
```

to this Class

```
public class Message extends Syncable<Message> implements Comparable<Message> {

    public UUID Id;
    public String Content;
    public Date DateCreated;
    public UUID ChatId;
    public UUID AccountId;
    public Boolean Internal;
    public Boolean Quotation;
    public Account Account;
    public Chat Chat;
    public Centipede<MessageRead> MessageRead;

    public Message() {
        this.MessageRead = new Centipede<MessageRead>();
    }
}
```

And getting this strange error

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.<init>(MappedByteBuffer.java:43)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:33)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.copy(DirectByteBuffer.java:52)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.duplicate(DirectByteBuffer.java:75)
        at com.android.dex.Dex.open(Dex.java:191)
        at com.android.dex.Dex$StringTable.get(Dex.java:893)
        at com.android.dex.Dex$StringTable.get(Dex.java:890)
        at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheString(Class.java:1334)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:731)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:705)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getSignature(AnnotationAccess.java:453)
        at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:824)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.getGenericSupertype($Gson$Types.java:249)
```

Yesterday everything was OK, and today, after Android Studio updated, i'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Gson libraries are missing after the update
try this

1)Put the Gson jar (in my case, gson-2.2.4.jar) into the libs folder

2)Right click it and hit `'Add as library'`

3)Ensure that `compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')` is in your `build.gradle` file

4)Do a clean buil

Comment: They are not missing... Gson is updated... Tried to parse to test classes and it worked for very simple cases... Still don't have any idea where this problem is occurring... ;(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from UUID to String and see if that works.

Comment: No, the problem does not change with String instead of UUID.